# How to use chained prototype for a string

Tags: javascript, prototype

I want to use chained prototype for a string. But one I return string prototype is no more applied. How to fix that without returning `this` by prototype method, same as native `String.prototype`.

```js
function StringUtil(str){
  this.str = str;
}

StringUtil.prototype.toCamelCase = function () {
  return this.str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(letter, index) {
    return index === 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
};

StringUtil.prototype.toSlug = function() {
  return this.str.toString().toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
    .replace(/^-+/, '')             // Trim - from start of text
    .replace(/-+$/, '');            // Trim - from end of text
};

var util = new StringUtil('this is a custom string');
console.log(util.toCamelCase()) // thisIsACustomString
console.log(util.toSlug()) // this-is-a-custom-string

util.toCamelCase().toSlug() // This does not work
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StringUtil.prototype.toCamelCase = function () {
  return this.str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(letter, index) {
    return index === 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
};
```

You are returning the value returned by `this.str.replace` same with `String.prototype.replace`'return (a string) .

Same with your next function .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning a `String` object inside your `StringUtil` methods (`replace` returns a new `string)`. So string prototype doesn't have the new methods that you are creating. You can fix it returning a new `StringUtil` object in your new methods:

```
function StringUtil(str){
  this.str = str;
}

StringUtil.prototype.toCamelCase = function () {
  return new StringUtil(this.str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(letter, index) {
    return index === 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/\s+/g, ''));
};
```

Comment: returning a new `StringUtil` object in all method will impact performance?

Comment: I think in this case will be not present any issue. Anyway you can follow @gurvinder372 approach and return `this` object just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `this` from your methods for chaining to work.

For example

```js
function StringUtil(str){
  this.str = str;
}

StringUtil.prototype.toCamelCase = function () {
  this.str = this.str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(letter, index) {
    return index === 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
  return this;
};

StringUtil.prototype.toSlug = function() {
  this.str = this.str.toString().toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
    .replace(/^-+/, '')             // Trim - from start of text
    .replace(/-+$/, '');            // Trim - from end of text
   return this;
};


StringUtil.prototype.setStr =function(str) {
   this.str = str;
   return this;
};

StringUtil.prototype.toString =function() {
   return this.str.toString();
};


var util = new StringUtil('this is a custom string');
console.log(util.toCamelCase().toString()) 
console.log(util.setStr("this is a custom string").toSlug().toString()) 

console.log(util.toCamelCase().toSlug().toString())
```

I have added a couple of methods to your class to explain the effect of chaining.

- toString() - Since you are returning `this`, `console.log` won't print the data in required format.
- setStr() - So, that you can see `toSlug` working on original string.